# Why does my Array is empty when I print it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

When moving my code to an MVC architecture, I tried diplaying my users login and password(written as `$mdp`) but when I print my variable stocking these data I get

`Array()`

And I dont know why here is the code of my Controler:

```
$modele = new \App\Models\authModele(); 
            $donnees = $modele->authenticate('dandre', 'oppg5');
            $data['resultat'] = $donnees;
            $user = $data;
            print_r($donnees);
```

The code of my model(authModele):

```
$db = db_connect(); 
           
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Visiteur WHERE login = ? AND mdp = ?';
 
            $resultat = $db->query($sql, [$login, $mdp]);

            $resultat = $resultat->getResult();
    
            return $resultat;
```

Any idea why my `print_r($donnees)` is answerd by `Array()` ?

I thougt is a typing problem but I don't see anything so I am lost.
The file Database is already set up and good

Comment: Have you tried debugging the issue? Does data from the database reach PHP? Is the SQL correct? Try taking it step by step, start with `$resultat`, does it have any data?

Comment: _"Any idea why my print_r($donnees) is answerd by Array() ?"_ - most likely, because your SQL query did not actually find any matching records.

Comment: Just as advice, you should try to not mix languages, I can english and french in your code, and respect cases, use snake case for your table names, pascal case for your class names...